I/flutter (17585): Error creating image: type 'PixelUint8' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast
late int alphaValue;
  late int redValue;
  late int greenValue;
  late int blueValue;

  int getAlpha(int pixel) {
    if (pixel is int) {
      return (pixel >> 24) & 0xFF;
    } else {
      // Gestione degli errori o valore di default nel caso in cui il valore di pixel non sia un intero
      return 0;
    }
  }

  int getRed(int pixel) {
    if (pixel is int) {
      return (pixel >> 16) & 0xFF;
    } else {
      // Gestione degli errori o valore di default
      return 0;
    }
  }

  int getGreen(int pixel) {
    if (pixel is int) {
      return (pixel >> 8) & 0xFF;
    } else {
      // Gestione degli errori o valore di default
      return 0;
    }
  }

  int getBlue(int pixel) {
    if (pixel is int) {
      return pixel & 0xFF;
    } else {
      // Gestione degli errori o valore di default
      return 0;
    }
  }



  Future<File> _createStartrail(List<File> images) async {
    if (images.isEmpty) {
      throw Exception('No images selected');
    }

    img.Image? startrailImage;

    for (final imageFile in images) {
      final bytes = await imageFile.readAsBytes();
      final image = img.decodeImage(Uint8List.fromList(bytes));

      if (image == null) continue;

      startrailImage ??= img.Image(width: image.width, height: image.height);

      for (int y = 0; y < image.height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < image.width; x++) {
          final pixel = image.getPixel(x, y);

          alphaValue = getAlpha(pixel as int);
          redValue = getRed(pixel as int);
          greenValue = getGreen(pixel as int);
          blueValue = getBlue(pixel as int);

          final newPixel = (alphaValue << 24) | (redValue << 16) | (greenValue << 8) | blueValue;

          startrailImage.setPixel(x, y, newPixel as img.Color);
        }
      }
    }

    final output = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    final outputPath = '${output.path}/startrail.png';

    final outputFile = File(outputPath);
    await outputFile.writeAsBytes(img.encodePng(startrailImage!));

    return outputFile;
  }








  // Aggiungi una variabile per tenere traccia dell'immagine sommata
  File? _combinedImage;

// Aggiungi un metodo per combinare le immagini e mostrare l'anteprima
  void _combineImages() {
    if (_images.isNotEmpty) {
      _createStartrail(_images).then((combinedImage) {
        setState(() {
          _combinedImage = combinedImage;
        });
      }).catchError((error) {
        // Gestione degli errori in caso di fallimento della creazione dell'immagine
        print('Errore durante la creazione dell\'immagine startrail: $error');
      });
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Camera Preview')),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: FutureBuilder<void>(
              future: _initializeControllerFuture,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  return AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                    child: CameraPreview(_controller),
                  );
                } else {
                  return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: _pickImages,
                child: const Text('Select Images'),
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 10),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: _combineImages, // Combinare le immagini quando si preme il pulsante
                child: const Text('Create Startrail'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          if (_imagePreviews.isNotEmpty)
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
              height: 100,
              child: ListView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                children: _imagePreviews,
              ),
            ),
          if (_combinedImage != null)
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Image.file(_combinedImage!),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}xt`

Hi guys I'm creating an app with Dart and Flutter. I select the images from the gallery and put them on the screen (up to this point the app works), when I go to add the images together I get this error
I/flutter (17585): Error creating image: type 'PixelUint8' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast

Things start to go wrong here:
final pixel = image.getPixel(x, y);
alphaValue = getAlpha(pixel as int);

pixel is not an int, it's a Pixel. Luckily, Pixel has getters and setters.
alphaValue = pixel.a;
redValue = pixel.r;

Looks like you want to set a pixel in another image. Use:
final newPixel = startTrailImage.getPixel(x, y)
  ..setRgba(redValue, greenValue, blueValue, alphaValue);
startrailImage.setPixel(x, y, newPixel);



This code does not generate errors but even if the images are added I don't see a startrail. Why?

Future<File> _createStartrail(List<File> images) async {
if (images.isEmpty) {
  throw Exception('No images selected');
}

img.Image? startrailImage;

for (final imageFile in images) {
  final bytes = await imageFile.readAsBytes();
  final image = img.decodeImage(Uint8List.fromList(bytes));

  if (image == null) continue;

  startrailImage ??= img.Image(width: image.width, height: image.height);

  for (int y = 0; y < image.height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < image.width; x++) {
      final pixel = image.getPixel(x, y);

      final alphaValue = pixel.a;
      final redValue = pixel.r;
      final greenValue = pixel.g;
      final blueValue = pixel.b;

      // Imposta il pixel combinato nella nuova immagine
      final newPixel = startrailImage.getPixel(x, y)
        ..setRgba(redValue, greenValue, blueValue, alphaValue);

      startrailImage.setPixel(x, y, newPixel);
    }
  }
}

// Salva l'immagine combinata come file
final output = await getTemporaryDirectory();
final outputPath = '${output.path}/startrail.png';

final outputFile = File(outputPath);
await outputFile.writeAsBytes(img.encodePng(startrailImage!));

return outputFile;

}

Plus I get this error "Bottom overflowed by 253 pixels"

`if (_imagePreviews.isNotEmpty)
        Expanded(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            child: Row(
              children: _imagePreviews,
            ),
          ),
        ),

      if (_combinedImage != null)
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Image.file(_combinedImage!),
        ),`


I tried using Flex but the app does not display the images chosen from the gallery on the screen


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
